# Callout mediator doe'snot giving any response in WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

While I am using call out mediator in wso2 esb , with DSS Endpoint I am
getting the request only, I am not getting response, even I put log in
the out sequence. Here I am sending my proxy service.

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="Binaryformat"
           transports="https http"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
             <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
             <log level="full">
                <property name="M1" value="*************Callout  PROXY*************"/>
             </log>

             <callout serviceURL="http://192.168.1.201:9769/services/emp_DataService/">
                <source type="envelope"/>
                <target key="response"/>
             </callout>
             <log level="full">
                <property name="Status" expression="get-property('response')"/>
             </log>
             <header name="To" action="remove"/>
             <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
             <!--<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>-->
             <send/>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="Status" expression="get-property('response')"/>
             </log>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
    <response>outonly</response>
                </format>
                <args/>
             </payloadFactory>
             <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callout mediator is synchronous, it will return the response in the same sequence (your inSequence, by doing a blocking call) : your outSequence is unnecessary.

however, you should add a faultSequence to log any error

you should use tcpmon (launch tcpmon in ESB_HOME/bin) between ESB and your endpoint to verify request content going to your service and verify if you obtain a response from your service.

Comment: My request is going well and getting response also,the issue is i am unable to send the response to client, can you please help on this.

Comment: Try to add this property in you inSequence, before <send/> :  <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>

Answer (score 5):

I think you have configured callout mediator wrongfully. Check for the callout mediator sample here

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+430%3A+Simple+Callout+Mediator+for+Synchronized+Web+Service+Invocation

As well as OUT-ONLY set to "true" mean on a message to indicate that no response message is expected for it once it is forwarded from the ESB. you can read more about OUT_ONLY and other properties from here http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Generic+Properties